# Typescript react: Type inference is not working for callback refs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My react component needs a callback ref only.
I'm using useState for a callback ref.

```
const [refElement, setReference] = useState(null);
```

Inside render:

```
<div
// this ref is throwing ts error
   ref={setArrowElement}
   style={styles.arrow}
   id="arrow"
/>
```

Typescript error : On `tsc`

```
- error TS2322: Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<null>>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<null>>' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'value' and 'instance' are incompatible.
      Type 'HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<null>'.
        Type 'HTMLDivElement' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<null>'.
          Type 'HTMLDivElement' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: null): null'.

216                         ref={setReference}
                            ~~~

  ../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:145:9
    145         ref?: LegacyRef<T>;
                ~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'


Found 1 error.
```

Comment: `ref` should be an HTML element, and you're assigning it a `setState` function

Comment: why do you `useState` instead of `useRef`

Comment: Cause I need a call back as reference thats why. `useRef` does not provide a callback

Comment: It's inferred from initial, which is of type `null`.

Comment: How does `setArrowElement` look like?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can fix this by typing your `useState` function:

```
const [refElement, setReference] = useState<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

...

<div ref={setReference} />
```

Comment: You can make this more flexible by using `HTMLElement` instead of `HTMLDivElement` - that way it will work with any element.